# What kind of query optimization can be expected?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

tl;dr; Will the query optimizer be able to optimize the `max` calls?

```
select id
    , max(case when this and that11 and that12 then 1 else 0 end) name1
    , max(case when this and that21 and that22 then 1 else 0 end) name2
    -- ... there's an average of 17 max() over 6 similar selects
    , max(case when this and thatN1 and thatN2 then 1 else 0 end) nameN
from firstTable
    join secondTable ...
    join thirdTable  ...
    join fourthTable ...
where (1=1)
```

---

We have a partnership with a data source such that when we want to access their data, we tell them what we want and they provide the query; we get copies but we don't have access to change it on the database nor do we have the ability to run a refactored version in a test environment. In one case, we were given a stored proc that included 6 instances similar to the above example; they only differ by the number of columns calculated with `max` and the `where` condition.

I spend most of my time at a higher level in ORMs but this looked suspect to me. It's maximizing what amounts to a Boolean. `max` cannot guarantee which of `1` or `1` will be returned; but even if it could, there's no more identifiable data so it's being used like an `Any()` check. `max` is an aggregate so it needs to traverse the whole set to find that max but ideally, it would break as soon as it found the first match.

We are having timeout issues and even though the owners of that system increased the timeout to an hour, it still fails when trying to get all the data we need. The query is generally pretty gnarly but this usage of `max` stuck out as a likely culprit so I wanted to get an idea if I was on the right track before scrutinizing the rest.

Am I right to believe this is at least inefficient? Are query optimizers (oracle in this case) "smart" enough to help with this if so?

Comment: I am pretty sure that Oracle's optimizer isn't that smart that it will see only zeros and ones are possible, so it can stop looking at an expression once it resulted in 1 for a row. And as a programmer I doubt that it could be coded efficiently to stop for some expressions and continue with the others. This can't be the issue. Running through a table, invoking the expressions and getting the maxes cannot be that slow. It is much more likely that either the joins are slow due to a lack of appropriate indexes or that they result in a huge intermediate data set that must be aggregated.

Comment: It is true, though, that separate exists clauses could be much faster than the joins. But that depends on the tables, their relations, and their indexes.

Comment: If your expressions don't contain any function invocations, then they should be quite cheap to calculate. I've never seen any issues caused by calculations, the main wait times on large datasets are IO, hashing, sorting and redistribution. Oracle have to perform all the joins before it will be able to construct rowset for aggregation, then it have to calculate a hash for each row to identify a group and only then calculate an expression. Decision to calculate or not may take  the same (or comparable) amount of time as the calculation itself and much less than row source processing

Comment: The query optimiser is primarily concerned with join order and access methods, unless there are any transformations such as predicate pushing or OR expansion that could help. From your description I don't see anything the optimiser could address. Does your system have enough memory for optimal hash joins and GROUP BY operations?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: No

As always, without showing us the queryplan, your guess is as good as ours so the below needs to be taken with a (huge) grain of salt:

Simply looking at the provided 'sample query' I see

- a bunch of `JOIN`s that may or may not be bottlenecking your query

  - Indexes play a huge role here
  - Up-to-date statistics play a huge role here
  - The 'layout' of your data may be influencing your query

    - if two tables join in a 1:1 fashion that's usually fine
    - if two tables join in a 1:100 fashion, and that happens for some others too then things will explode really, really fast.
- a bunch of this1, this2, ... that1, that2, .. that may or may not be bottlenecking your query

  - keep in mind that whatever fields are being used here, they also need to be fetched from the tables (read: they may not be part of the indexes being used to join the tables so they'll require extra IO or the optimizer might decide to skip the index and simply scan the table instead)
  - if 'this' is something like `'fieldA < fieldB'` then (IMHO) the overhead should be minimal
  - if 'this' is something like `myFunction(fieldA, fieldB) > x` then yeah, this potentially could be eating into your performance
- `WHERE 1=1` implying there could be gazillions of records involved here

  - Processing heaps of data IS going to take time, regardless of your approach

Again, without the actual queryplan this is all just guessing from my part. That said, if I'd be presented with this situation I might consider pre-aggregating all the fields involved first as to avoid duplicate 'this and that' calculations, whether that's feasible depends a lot on the 'this and thats' involved.

Alternatively, converting the query to 17-ish `WHERE EXISTS()` queries as you suggest might indeed be a valid approach but its performance will depend on the data again:

- imagine that all 17 return 'false' you may end up running the above query 17 times for it's full length rather than just the once with some post-calculations you do now. Keep in mind however that even in that case there will be more chances that indexes help you out (bigtime!) here, which is 'less likely' for the current construction.
- also, it's not just 17 `WHERE EXISTS()`, it's 17 `WHERE EXISTS()` for each `id` (!)

All in all, a big YMMV. Given the input presented there is no simple answer I fear -- is there ever with SQL?. Try to get a hold of the queryplan and draw conclusions from that. If there is no way to obtain that, some experimenting might be in order...

Comment: Thanks for the info; I'll try to get my hands on the query plan.